# Deserialize and parse only needed arrays from JSON Array

Tags: c#, json, winforms

My C# Windows Application uses `JavaScriptSerializer` to request JSON from certain URL.

JSON looks something like below:

```
{"outcomes":[{"outcome_coef":2.8,"outcome_id":159370020,"outcome_name":"first","outcome_type_id":4,"outcome_visible":"yes","participant_number":1,"outcome_perc_stat":0.0},
{"outcome_coef":1.19,"outcome_id":159370022,"outcome_name":"second","outcome_type_id":5,"outcome_visible":"yes","participant_number":2,"outcome_perc_stat":0.0},
{"outcome_coef":1.01,"outcome_id":159370021,"outcome_name":"third","outcome_type_id":6,"outcome_visible":"yes","participant_number":3,"outcome_perc_stat":0.0}]}
```

For example, I only need to get `outcome_coef` and `outcome_id`. The rest of the array is not needed.

I am trying to use the following code:

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var response = js.Deserialize<Response>(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

My Response class looks like this:

```
public class Response
{
    public Outcomes[] outcomes { get; set; }
}

public class Outcomes
{
    public float outcome_coef { get; set; }
    public int outcome_id { get; set; }
}
```

But it is not working.

How can I parse only needed part out of JSON without declaring all the array names inside my class?

EDIT:

Sometimes JSON comes in the following format and after deserializing it gives me null Exception (it comes with additional arrays at the start or at the end):

```
{"event_history":[],"outcomes":[{"outcome_coef":2.8,"outcome_id":159370020,"outcome_name":"first","outcome_type_id":4,"outcome_visible":"yes","participant_number":1,"outcome_perc_stat":0.0},
{"outcome_coef":1.19,"outcome_id":159370022,"outcome_name":"second","outcome_type_id":5,"outcome_visible":"yes","participant_number":2,"outcome_perc_stat":0.0},
{"outcome_coef":1.01,"outcome_id":159370021,"outcome_name":"third","outcome_type_id":6,"outcome_visible":"yes","participant_number":3,"outcome_perc_stat":0.0}], "event_stats":null}
```

Do I have to crate variables for other arrays as well in this case?

Comment: don't use JasonSerilizer. It is limited and slow. Microsoft itself uses [Newtonsoft.Json](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json) instead.

Comment: Instead of JavaScriptSerializer use Json.Net. JavaScriptSerializer is an old class with limited Json support. Json.NET is almost a standard, used in Web API and MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works perfectly fine with Json.NET:

```
void Main()
{
    var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\text.json");
    var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(jsonString);
}

public class Response
{
    public Outcomes[] outcomes { get; set; }
}

public class Outcomes
{
    [JsonProperty("outcome_coef")]
    public float OutcomeCoef { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("outcome_id")]
    public int OutcomeId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: As you said, it works perfect, but please take a look to my Edit. When there are additional arrays before or after `outcomes` it gives me null while parsing.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [JSON.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) you don't need a model at all:

```
dynamic result = JsonConvert.Deserialize(jsonString);
var myArray = result.outcomes[1]; // get array at index 1
Console.WriteLine(myArray.outcome_coef); // output: 1.19
```

Comment: You might need to have a nullcheck here before directly assigning.

Comment: @HarveySpecter of course... i assume the OP knows that the (short) answer lacks of null checking.

Comment: Hahaha. Like they say, Never assume, always specify.